# Getting a incorrect WHERE syntax with my sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hope someone can help , I keep getting an Incorrect "WHERE" syntax with the following sql statement

```
using (SqlCommand selectT = new SqlCommand("Select [TR_RegNumber] 
                                            FROM dbo.TrailerDetail 
                                            WHERE [TR_Routes] = '" +trailersRoutesAllocations[i]+ "'" + " 
                                            AND WHERE [TR_Classficiation] = '" +trailersVragClassification[i]+ "'", con))
```

I am coding in C# (using Visual Studio)

Comment: Just ONE `WHERE` is required then use AND and OR as often as required like `WHERE a='b' AND x=y`

Comment: What's the content of the `trailersRoutesAllocations`? Please use parameterized queries instead of inserting these values directly into your query. This code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @RiggsFolly your edit made the code snippet invalid C#.

Comment: @RenéVogt Feel free to fix it

Comment: Looks more like SQL Server code than MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one WHERE more. Write just one WHERE like here:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 ...;
```

this is copy from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra where in the AND condition and it should work.

```
using (SqlCommand selectT = new SqlCommand("Select [TR_RegNumber] 
                                        FROM dbo.TrailerDetail 
                                        WHERE [TR_Routes] = '" +trailersRoutesAllocations[i]+ "'" + " 
                                        AND [TR_Classficiation] = '" +trailersVragClassification
```